# Jwplayer 5 settings

Tags: jwplayer

**Have a nice forum, what i wanna do is, to make code seen player.swf = id in source code and wanna be read the player in jwplayer5. I dont wanna show subtitle and url.The embed i use now is sending id to config.php and to be read from there by player yet it shows source codes**
mY Codes ;

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='940' height='460' id='single1' name='single1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
        <param name='movie' value='_jwplayer/player.swf'>
        <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
        <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
        <param name='wmode' value='opaque'>
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
        <param name='flashvars' value='config=_jwplayer/config.php?id=<?php echo $row['s_id']; ?>'>
        <embed id='single2' name='single2' src='_jwplayer/player.swf' width='940' height='460' bgcolor='#000000' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' flashvars='config=_jwplayer/config.php?id=<?php echo $row['s_id']; ?>'/>
    </object>
```

Comment: Well, the config php file still needs to output into something that can be read client side by the JW Player. Are you trying to hide your config?